# How to join 2 queries in Arel, one being an aggregation of the other (Rails 5.2.4)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

My application monitors ProductionJobs, derived from BusinessProcesses in successive versions. Thus the unique key of ProductionJob class is composed of **business_process_id** and **version** fields.

Initially, the ProductionJob index would display the list of objects (including all versions) using an Arel structured query (@production_jobs).

But it is more convinient to only show the last version of each ProductionJob. So I created a query (@recent_jobs) to retrieve the last version of the ProductionJob for a given BusinessProces.

Joining the 2 queries should return only the last version of each ProductionJob. This is what I can't achieve with my knowledge of Arel, and I would be grateful if you could show me how to do!

Here is the code in **production_jobs_controller**:

a) Arel objects setup

```
private

def jobs
  ProductionJob.arel_table
end

def processes   # jobs are built on the processes
  BusinessProcess.arel_table
end

def flows       # flows provide a classifiaction to processes
  BusinessFlow.arel_table
end

def owners      # owner of the jobs
  User.arel_table.alias('owners')
end

def production_jobs     # job index
  jobs.
  join(owners).on(jobs[:owner_id].eq(owners[:id])).
  join(processes).on(jobs[:business_process_id].eq(processes[:id])).
  join(flows).on(processes[:business_flow_id].eq(flows[:id])).
  join_sources
end

def job_index_fields
  [jobs[:id],
    jobs[:code].as("job_code"),
    jobs[:status_id],
    jobs[:created_at],
    jobs[:updated_by],
    jobs[:updated_at],
    jobs[:business_process_id],
    jobs[:version],
    processes[:code].as("process_code"),
    flows[:code].as("statistical_activity_code"),
    owners[:name].as("owner_name")]
end

def order_by
  [jobs[:code], jobs[:updated_at].desc]
end

# Latest jobs
def recent_jobs
  jobs.
  join(owners).on(jobs[:owner_id].eq(owners[:id])).
  join_sources
end

def recent_jobs_fields
  [ jobs[:code],
    jobs[:business_process_id].as('bp_id'),
    jobs[:version].maximum.as('max_version')
  ]
end
```

b) The index method

```
  # GET /production_jobs or /production_jobs.json
  def index
    @production_jobs = ProductionJob.joins(production_jobs).
                                      pgnd(current_playground).
                                      where("business_flows.code in (?)", current_user.preferred_activities).
                                      order(order_by).
                                      select(job_index_fields).
                                      paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page])

    @recent_jobs = ProductionJob.joins(recent_jobs).select(recent_jobs_fields).group(:business_process_id, :code)

    @selected_jobs = @production_jobs.joins(@recent_jobs).where(business_process_id: :bp_id, version: :max_version)
```

Unfortunately, @selected_jobs returns a nil object, even though @production_jobs and @recent_jobs show linkable results. how should I build the @selected_jobs statement to reach the expected result?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, I finally included the sub-request in a 'where ... in()' clause. This may not be optimal, and I am open to other proposals.

The result can be understood as the following:

1. @recent_jobs provide the list ProductionJobs'last versions, based on their code and version
2. @production_jobs provide the list of all ProductionJobs
3. @selected_jobs adds the ***where*** clause to @production_jobs, based on the @recent_jobs:

The last request is updated to:

```
@selected_jobs = @production_jobs
                 .where("(production_jobs.code,
                          production_jobs.business_process_id,
                          production_jobs.version) 
                          in (?)", 
                        @recent_jobs
                        )
```

It works this way, but I'd be glad to receive suggestions to enhance this query. Thanks!